# Docusign API with python sdk: "Could not deserialize key data."

Tags: python, docusignapi

I'm following the recipe here https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client and getting an authentication error, "Could not deserialize key data" on line 33:

`oauth_login_url = api_client.get_jwt_uri(integrator_key, redirect_uri, oauth_base_url)`

I believe I have all the necessary settings active in the Docusign demo account:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocH6Z.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/40uzp.jpg

and in the credentials parameters of the script.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/swdCt.jpg

(I've color-coded them to show what value I've put where.)  The green item is the public key that Docusign generated, and the path to `private_key_filename` is the corresponding private key, also generated by Docusign.

Do I need to create a secret key (between Redirect URI and RSA Keypairs)?  Is there something wrong with the private key file?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this [video](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-developing-docusign-application-authentication/). It was recently published on the DocuSign blog and it shows how to create a JWT Token in python

Answer (score 0):

If you are not owning an email domain or cannot claim email domain in the DocuSign then you need to use User Consent else you can use Admin Consent. Please find the link [Service Integration using JWT](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html) to understand the flow of creating JWT. For User Consent, you need to start with either the [Authorization Code Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html) or the [Implicit Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_implicit.html). For Admin Consent, you need to claim email domain in DocuSign then you can create Access token for any user in your DS Account with same claimed email domain. To use User Consent using JWT, please check video at [User Consent using Python](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-developing-docusign-application-authentication/)